# Unable to connect Android version 2.3.6 phone on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am unable to connect android version 2.3.6 device to Ubuntu 12.04. I want to connect that device for developing and debugging purposes with Android Eclipse. Is there any driver problem? Apart from this 2.3.6 version device, I can access all other devices with various versions. There is no issue for other versions.

Is Gingerbread not supported on Linux / Ubuntu OS?

Comment: android device model?

Comment: @fidal1989 :its samsung s3 with 2.3.6

Comment: how come galaxy s3 has 2.3.6? are you sure?

Comment: sorry its my mistake ,its  Samsung S5302 model number

Comment: I have Samsung S5300, it works fine in ubuntu & mint. check whether usb debugging is enabled?

Comment: is there any additional settings i should follow in linux terminals  for that ?

Comment: try restarting adb after you connect device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the device correctly?
Goto Settings->Applications->Development->and be sure USB debugging Enabled(Checked).
Then In Eclipse Click on DDMS(Windows->Open Perspective->Other->DDMS. your device will be listed there. if not try restarting eclipse.

Comment: @Vignesheran.m : yes I done all this thing but cant get any result .

Comment: there may be problem with your usb cable.

Comment: i tried different USB cables also but it cant work .i m confused about that is there any drivers problem ??

Comment: i have checked with xperia with no drivers working, in linux mint and eclipse.

Comment: :Is GINGERBREAD is not supported in Linux / Ubuntu OS ?? do u work with it before ?

Comment: im just now tested gingerbread in linuxmint have u installed eclipse? and u checked it in ddms?

Comment: does your device works on other systems? windows/Linux?

Comment: what version of ubuntu and eclipse u  using?

Comment: Eclipse indigo and Ubuntu 12.04 and device version is Android 2.3.6

Comment: i think its an old version of eclipse and android sdk , u just try the latest android sdk bundle  here [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) that may be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you can try on your **command-line**:

1. *lsusb*

   - does this show your device? If not, something with the driver is wrong - or your device is not connected (broken cable?).
2. *adb devices*

   - does this show your device as attached? If not, there might be a problem with either:

     - phone is not set to debug mode (described above, need to enable developer on the device first)
     - there might be an issue with your */etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules* if you work with linux/osx, I cannot help you with windows though...